# iOS AVPlayer time observer crash

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, ios12, swift4.2

Ever since upgrading to iOS 12/XCode 10 and Swift 4.2, I am observing crashes in AVPlayer time observer. The crash happens when playing the same video but not every time which is strange. Here is the code. I have verified that interval is 0.004 and not 0. This happens even if I set interval to 1.0/30.0 manually instead of computing. I suspect crash is either related to some changes in Swift 4.2 or iOS 12.

```
        let width = Double(self.playerView.bounds.width)
        var interval = 0.5*duration.seconds/width

        /* The time label needs to update at least once per second. */
        if interval > 1.0 {
           interval = 1.0
        }

        playerObserver = player.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTime(seconds: interval, preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(NSEC_PER_SEC)), queue: DispatchQueue.main, using: { [weak self] time in
            self?.syncScrubber()
        })             

   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[AVPeriodicTimebaseObserver initWithTimebase:interval:queue:block:] invalid parameter not satisfying: ((Boolean)(CMTimeCompare(interval, kCMTimeZero) > 0))'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1e7a57ef8 0x1e6c25a40 0x1edab0be0 0x1eda65b18 0x10278eaec 0x10277d104 0x10277dc74 0x1e84c9d4c 0x1e84cc1e0 0x1e84c95d4 0x1eda91290 0x1043e3840 0x1043e4de4 0x1043f2a94 0x1e79e61bc 0x1e79e1084 0x1e79e05b8 0x1e9c54584
```